# Google maps custom map tile/overlay and controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, icloud

How did Apple make the custom map tile/overlay and controls for iCloud's Find My iPhone Web App.

It has a really nice grid on top of the map and the zoom controls etc are all custom.

Maybe I missed it in the docs but couldn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody's reference if they stumble across this question.

The answer is in the docs here - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles

Answer (score 1):

The answer is above for the deprecated JavaScript API v2, which will stop working on November 19th 2013.  This is the equivalent for v3:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls